# Caught exception while polling pending tasks

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

Caught exception while polling pending tasks.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT t.PK, ts.hjmpTS, t.PROCESSING_TIME FROM tasks_aux_queue t JOIN (SELECT PK, hjmpTS from tasks) ts ON t.PK = ts.PK WHERE ((t.RANGE_VALUE BETWEEN ? AND ? AND t.NODE_ID = -1 AND t.NODE_GROUP = '---') OR (t.NODE_ID = ? OR t.NODE_GROUP IN (?))) AND PROCESSING_TIME <= NOW() ORDER BY EXECUTION_TIME LIMIT ? FOR UPDATE]; General error; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: General error

This type of error getting when I am running the hybrisserver.bat debug
#hybris

I tried ant clean all still the same error